# Is it possible for me to add a favicon to a site that doesn't have one, for the sake of my bookmarks bar?

Tags: google-chrome, web, favicon

My organization's Basecamp site lacks a favicon, which leaves my Chrome Bookmarks Bar looking messy (and means I can't leave the bookmark title blank for an icon-only bookmark). Is there any way I could add my own favicon to any arbitrary site that lacks one, just for personal use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/3032/google_chrome_how_to_change_icons_on_the_bookmarks_bar/

> First, you’ll need to download and
>   install the free SQLite Database
>   browser.
>
> Now, open Google Chrome and visit the
>   site(s) that have the favicon you want
>   displayed in your Bookmarks bar. After
>   you have completed this, close Google
>   Chrome.
>
> We are ready to change icons:
>
> 1. Open SQLite Database browser.
> 2. Go to the toolbar and select the Open (folder) icon to bring up the
>      Open window.
> 3. When the open window appears, you will need to browse to the following
>      directory:
>
> In Windows XP: `C:\Documents and
>   Settings\\Local Settings\Application
>   Data\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default`
>
> In Windows Vista:
>   `C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User
>   Data\Default`
>
> Note: change username to your
>   username.
>
> 4. Open the History file.
> 5. Select the Browse Data tab.
> 6. Select urls from the Table dropdown.
> 7. The table will appear with the following columns: id, url, title,
>      visit_count, typed_count,
>      last_visit_time, hidden, favicon_id
>      and starred_id. Our main focus will be
>      on the favicon_id and starred_id
>      columns, but you will need to pay
>      attention to the title column as well.
>      Any row that has a value other than 0
>      in the starred_id column is a
>      bookmark. Any row that has a value
>      other than 0 in the favicon_id column
>      has an icon associated with it (if it
>      has a 0, it will use the default
>      icon).
> 8. Locate one of the sites you browsed to earlier that contains the desired
>      favicon that you wish to use. Make
>      sure it has a value in the favicon_id
>      column. When you have located it, make
>      note of the value that is in the
>      favicon_id column.
> 9. Now locate the bookmark that you want to assign the favicon to. The
>      title may appear more than once, so
>      you must make sure that you select the
>      record that has a value in the
>      starred_id column.
> 10. Double-click the favicon_id record (the one that is 0) to open the Edit
>       database cell window.
> 11. Change the 0 to the value you got from Step 8.
> 12. Click the Apply Changes button.
> 13. Repeat this process until you have finished assigning icons to your
>       bookmarks.
> 14. Go to the toolbar and click the Save icon.
>
> Now open up Google Chrome and check
>   out your Bookmarks bar.

Comment: do add more than just a link to your answer - if the site goes down then answer becomes useles..