# How can I force a bookmark on the toolbar to use a specific favicon?

Tags: google-chrome, favicon

I have a bookmark to https://tornexto.appspot.com/next?folder=comics.  The app that serves that page just does 302 redirect to next item from my comics folder on [The Old Reader](http://theoldreader.com).  The site has a favicon ([image]) and it does show up sometimes, but it tends to get overridden by the comics' favicons.  Is there any way to tell Chrome to always use the same favicon for a site?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I add a favicon to a bookmarklet in Google Chrome?](http://superuser.com/questions/212722/how-can-i-add-a-favicon-to-a-bookmarklet-in-google-chrome) or [Is it possible for me to add a favicon to a site that doesn't have one, for the sake of my bookmarks bar?](http://superuser.com/questions/153383/is-it-possible-for-me-to-add-a-favicon-to-a-site-that-doesnt-have-one-for-the)

Comment: @Raystafarian The accepted solution on that question did not work.  After visiting the URL it changed again to the comic's favicon instead of the tornexto favicon.

Comment: @Raystafarian The other solution (the I hate your favicon extension) is not practical either.  It replaces the favicon on a per URL basis.  I would need to replace the favicon for every comic I visit (too many to be practical) and I don't want their favicons replaced.  Only the one favicon associated with the bookmark.

Comment: Ah, you might need an add-on then. I don't run chrome, so I'll jump on out of this question.